# JavaFX loading system icons in a background thread

Tags: java, javafx

I have a file browser component in my app (TableView), and I load the icons of files via `FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon()`. Now, this is quite slow as I also need to convert the icon to BufferedImage, and that to JavaFX Image. So I needed to push this all to background thread(s). I created an IconLoadingTask, that loads a single icon - and during `updateItem()` of TableView I push these IconLoadingTasks to ExecutorService. It works, but could be improved.

The problem I have is that if the folder has lots of icons, and the user quickly drags the scrollbar, lots of "redundant" icons are loaded, stalling the thread(s) and resulting in often not seeing the icons that matter at the time: the ones that are currently displayed in the TableView.

Anyone have ideas how to solve this issue? I was thinking of accessing the vertical scrollbar of TableView and listening to it (and perhaps only update after scroll has been released), but I'm not sure how to even access the scrollbar... and maybe there's a simpler solution that escapes me.

**EDIT:**

Well, well. I created a minimal, complete and verifiable example out of my Kotlin code into Java code, and I cannot reproduce the "effect" anymore. It appears to work now as I intended it to in the first place. So it seems I just have to figure what "extra" I am doing in my main application's code. Anyways, here's the apparently working sample code.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class IconLoadTest extends Application {

    public static class FileEntry {
        public Path path;
        private Image icon;

        public FileEntry(Path path) {
            this.path = path;
        }

        synchronized void setIcon(Image icon) {
            this.icon = icon;
        }

        synchronized Image getIcon() {
            return icon;
        }

        public void setPath(Path path) {
            this.path = path;
        }

        public Path getPath() {
            return path;
        }
    }

    class MyTableCell extends TableCell<FileEntry, Path> {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Path item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty || item == null) {
                setText("");
                setGraphic(null);
                return;
            }

            setText(item.getFileName().toString());

            Image icon = dataMap.get(item).getIcon();
            if (icon == null) {
                setGraphic(null);
                executor.execute(new IconLoadingTask(item));
            } else {
                setGraphic(new ImageView(icon));
            }
        }
    }

    class IconLoadingTask extends Task<Void>  {

        private Path path;

        IconLoadingTask(Path path) {
            this.path = path;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void call() {

            FileEntry entry = dataMap.get(path);
            if (entry.icon != null) {
                return null;
            }

            entry.setIcon(getIcon(path.toFile()));

            // Refresh currently visible items
            Platform.runLater(() -> table.refresh());

            return null;
        }
    }

    private TableView<FileEntry> table = new TableView<>();

    // Table data
    private HashMap<Path, FileEntry> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
    private List<FileEntry> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(table);

        TableColumn<FileEntry, Path> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("path"));
        table.getColumns().add(nameCol);
        nameCol.setCellFactory(tableColumn -> new MyTableCell());

        // Sort so that dirs come first
        nameCol.setComparator((o1, o2) -> {
            if (Files.isDirectory(o1) && !Files.isDirectory(o2)) {
                return -1;
            } else if (!Files.isDirectory(o1) && Files.isDirectory(o2)) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return o1.toString().toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.toString().toLowerCase());
            }
        });

        // Set to a directory with lots of files (e.g. System32 on Windows)
        String directory = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\";

        // Load files from directory, and create entries for table
        Path dir = Paths.get(directory);
        List<Path> files = listContents(dir);
        for (Path p : files) {
            FileEntry entry = new FileEntry(p);
            data.add(entry);
            dataMap.put(p, entry);
        }
        table.setItems((ObservableList<FileEntry>) data);

        // Sort
        table.getSortOrder().add(table.getColumns().get(0));
        table.sort();

        // Display the app
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 480);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Icon Background Loading");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // Gets directory contents
    private static List<Path> listContents(Path directory) {
        ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Files.newDirectoryStream(directory).forEach(paths::add);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return paths;
    }

    // Gets a system icon for a file
    private static Image getIcon(File file) {
        Icon ico = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file);
        java.awt.Image awtImage = ((ImageIcon) ico).getImage();
        BufferedImage bImg;
        if (awtImage instanceof BufferedImage) {
            bImg = (BufferedImage) awtImage;
        } else {
            bImg = new BufferedImage(
                    awtImage.getWidth(null),
                    awtImage.getHeight(null),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
            );
            Graphics graphics = bImg.createGraphics();
            graphics.drawImage(awtImage, 0, 0, null);
            graphics.dispose();
        }
        return SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bImg, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(IconLoadTest.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the code ([mcve] ) would have been clearer and shorter than the attempt to describe it.

Comment: Alrighty, I will create one a bit later.